# Morphing between two mesh objects

Tags: modeling, shape-keys

I have a double curved mesh, which I UV unwrapped, exported as SVG, imported back into Blender, cleaned up, and scaled up to achieve an unrolled, flat mesh. How could the original mesh be morphed into the flat one?

[image]

I have tried shrinkwrap as suggested in [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23872/shape-key-morphing-between-two-meshes-with-different-vertices) question, but unfortunately, it doesn't produce the desired result.

Comment: Have you tried the shape keys?

Comment: @dimitarsp, does this morph target have the same Vertex Count and Topology as the start position, (just the locations of the Vertices are modified?)

Comment: @Gonzou i am currently faking it with Shape Keys, but I am looking to achieve the precise target flattened morph shape shown above

Comment: @zeffii the vertex count is the same, but I doubt the vertex order is the same, since I spent a bit of time cleaning up the topology from the imported UV Unwrap SVG

Comment: The best mesh morphs between _state one_ and _state two_ are when there exists a relationship between vertex locations. Maybe you'd like to share the blend?

Comment: Have you tried the [transfer Shape key](http://www.blender.org/manual/animation/shape_keys.html#shape-keys-panel) option? Also [this answer explains](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/36599/935) reordering the vertex indices, which should get them to match.